# Can't Install MySQL-Connector Library

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pip

I was using the mysql-connector 2.1.8 for a while and out of a sudden, it was no longer available.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector==2.1.8 (from versions: 2.2.8)
```

I tried installing some newer versions, like 2.2.5. Which literally worked once and then didn't on a server.

And the latest version 2.2.8 gives an error like this:

```
Collecting mysql-connector==2.2.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/78/049f747325ce0154263cd1b10fe7ea9ddb17e839111c6f8f824d5964cfb5/mysql-connector-2.2.8.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector
  Running setup.py install for mysql-connector ... error
    Complete output from command /home/liudas/PycharmProjects/eneba_what_place/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-7rlbpvfn/mysql-connector/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-kbw8r138/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/liudas/PycharmProjects/eneba_what_place/venv/include/site/python3.6/mysql-connector:
    usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: -c --help-commands
       or: -c cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install -U setuptools wheel
```

Newer package version might require newer features of setuptools or wheel, so it's what causes `--single-version-externally-managed not recognized`
A good thing to keep such core packages up to date, plus they are almost always backwards compatible.

Comment: Please explain how this solves the problem.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer